# Python Constraint Optimization Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am working on a Fantasy Football program and having an issue with a constraint. A fantasy team is made up of 1QB, 2RBs 3WRs 1TE, 1DEF and 1FLEX (which can be a RB, WR or TE)

My output is duplicating players. So, For example, if John Doe fills the RB position, I need him to not fill the FLEX position. I am at a loss of how to get this constraint done. Maybe a name comparison to ensure names don't equal each other?

**Any advice would be greatly appreciated!**

Here is some sample data:

```
| position | displayName         | Roster   | Position | salary | points |
|----------+---------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------|
| RB       | Christian McCaffrey | 15033483 | RB/FLEX  | 10000  | 30.95  |
| WR       | Michael Thomas      | 15033799 | WR/FLEX  | 9000   | 24.62  |
| QB       | Lamar Jackson       | 15033397 | QB       | 8100   | 29.85  |
| RB       | Dalvin Cook         | 15033485 | RB/FLEX  | 7900   | 21.62  |
```

```
# Set constraints
##################################################################
salaries = {}
points = {}

for pos in availables.position.unique():
    available_pos = availables[availables.position == pos]
    salary = list(available_pos[["displayName","salary"]].set_index("displayName").to_dict().values())[0]
    point = list(available_pos[["displayName","points"]].set_index("displayName").to_dict().values())[0]
    salaries[pos] = salary
    points[pos] = point

pos_num_available = {
    "QB": 1,
    "RB": 2,
    "WR": 3,
    "TE": 1,
    "FLEX": 1,
    "DST": 1
}


pos_flex = {
    "QB": 0,
    "RB": 1,
    "WR": 1,
    "TE": 1,
    "FLEX": 0,
    "DST": 0
}


pos_flex_available = 3
SALARY_CAP = 50000

_vars = {k: LpVariable.dict(k, v, cat="Binary") for k, v in points.items()}
##################################################################
# Problem Definition
##################################################################

prob = LpProblem("Fantasy", LpMaximize)
rewards = []
costs = []
position_constraints = []


for k, v in _vars.items():
     costs += lpSum([salaries[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
     rewards += lpSum([points[k][i] * _vars[k][i] for i in v])
     prob += lpSum([_vars[k][i] for i in v]) <= pos_num_available[k]
     prob += lpSum([pos_flex[k] * _vars[k][i] for i in v]) <= pos_flex_available

prob += lpSum(rewards)
prob += lpSum(costs) <= SALARY_CAP
prob.solve()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cleaned up your code a bit for readability. The structure is exactly the same, it's just some syntax things.

Consider the following:

```py
import pulp as pl
import pandas as pd

availables = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["RB", "Christian McCaffrey", 15033483, "RB/FLEX", 10000, 30.95],
        ["WR", "Michael Thomas", 15033799, "WR/FLEX", 9000, 24.62],
        ["QB", "Lamar Jackson", 15033397, "QB", 8100, 29.85],
        ["RB", "Dalvin Cook", 15033485, "RB/FLEX", 7900, 21.62]
    ],
    columns=["position", "displayName", "Roster", "Position", "salary", "points"]
)

##################################################################
# Set constraints
##################################################################
salaries = {}
points = {}
players = {}

for position in availables.position.unique():
    available_for_position = availables[availables.position == position]
    players[position] = list(available_for_position.Roster.values)

    salaries[position] = {
        player_roster: salary for player_roster, salary in
        zip(players[position], available_for_position.salary.values)
    }
    points[position] = {
        player_roster: _points for player_roster, _points in
        zip(players[position], available_for_position.points.values)
    }

positions_available = {
    "QB": 1,
    "RB": 2,
    "WR": 3,
    "TE": 1,
    "FLEX": 1,
    "DST": 1
}

flexible_positions = ("RB", "WR", "TE")

SALARY_CAP = 50000

# Player variables['QB'][15033483] denotes whether Lamar Jackson is selected
variables = {position: pl.LpVariable.dict(position, players[position], cat="Binary")
             for position in players}

##################################################################
# Problem Definition
##################################################################

prob = pl.LpProblem("Fantasy", pl.LpMaximize)
rewards = []
costs = []
number_of_selected_players = []

for position, players in variables.items():
    for player, player_selected in players.items():
        # If this player is selected, he will add salaries and points
        costs += salaries[position][player] * player_selected
        rewards += points[position][player] * player_selected
        number_of_selected_players += player_selected

    # Of this position, if it does not support FLEX, at most `positions_available`
    # are supported. If it does support FLEX, increment that by
    # `flexible_positions_available`
    if position not in flexible_positions:
        prob += pl.lpSum(players.values()) == positions_available[position]
    else:
        # We need at least `positions_available` players on this position and at
        # most`positions_available + flexible_positions_available` players
        prob += pl.lpSum(players.values()) >= positions_available[position]
        prob += (pl.lpSum(players.values())
                          <= positions_available[position] + positions_available["FLEX"])

# In total, we need exactly `positions_available` players
prob += pl.lpSum(number_of_selected_players) == sum(positions_available.values())

prob += pl.lpSum(rewards)
prob += pl.lpSum(costs) <= SALARY_CAP
prob.solve()
```

You keep track per player whether he has been selected. Then, you allow for at most `positions_available` players in that position, unless it's a "flexible" position, then you allow for between `positions_available` and `positions_available + positions_available['FLEX']`.

Because you require exactly 9 players in total, the only degree of freedom for the problem is to select one of the flexible players to fill that final flexible slot.